# How to get uclibc visible in crosstool-ng config menu?

Tags: embedded-linux, uclibc, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to build a crosstool-ng toolchain and I'm following the [bootlin training](https://bootlin.com/docs/). In this training, it seems that the C library that has been chosen is the UCLIBC library. However, after I downloaded the prebuilt toolchain from github repository and then launch the menuconfig , I noticed that the only 2 possible library to choose are newlib and none. Although I have the uclib in the crosstool-ng directory, I couldnt see it in the menu .
Any idea how can I have Uclibc with ct-ng toolchain ? Thanks.

Comment: I would rather use Buildroot Linux distribution where all such questions should be answered already.

Answer (score 2):

I am following the same tutorial as you do and ended up in the same situation. What I forgot was to load the Cortex-A5 sample with the command

`./ct-ng arm-cortexa5-linux-uclibcgnueabihf`

before going through the configuration modifications with

`./ct-ng menuconfig`.

I hope you still have the motivation to follow along this tutorial !

Best,

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I will try this out by the end of this week ;)